# Put a caller on hold with twilio client

Tags: c#, twilio

I am developing an application with twilio client.
I need to implement a Hold button which puts a caller on hold for a while by playing music track. and get the caller back by using same Hold button.

I can redirect the caller to twiml url which plays hold music. but how to get back that caller on the line again?

Is there any way to implement this?

Answer (score 1):

Here is an entry on Twilio's Blog that outlines call redirection:

[Call Redirection via the Twilio REST API](http://www.twilio.com/blog/2009/09/call-queueing-putting-callers-on-hold-calll-redirect-new-url-new-feature.html)